# C# - Function to randomise case of four strings always returns each string in the same case

Tags: c#, function, random, capitalization

I'm trying to build a basic random password generator in a Windows form. I have a list of words (all lower case), four of which get picked at random. Each word gets passed to a function to randomly change the case (capitalise the first character, capitalise the entire word, or just return the string in lower case) and then added to another list like so:

```
var dictionary = new List<String> { "aaron", "abandoned", "aberdeen" etc... };
int index;
index = random.Next(dictionary.Count);
string one = dictionary[index];
one = randomCase(one);
pwarray.Add(one);
```

This code is then duplicated for strings `two`, `three` and `four`. My function to randomise the case while not fancy is as so:

```
        private string randomCase (string word)
        {
            string changed;
            Random r = new Random();
            int n = r.Next(1, 29);

            // Output number to check it's not the same each time
            MessageBox.Show(n.ToString());
            if (n >= 1 || n <= 9)
            {
                // First letter capatalised
                changed = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(word.ToLower());
                return changed;
            }
            else if (n >= 10 || n <= 19)
            {
                // Word capitalised 
                changed = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(word.ToUpper());
                return changed;
            }
            else if (n >= 20 || n <= 29)
            {
                // Word left as lower case
                return word;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

I've added output message boxes to show what random number `n` is to aid with troubleshooting. When I run the app, I get different numbers from my `randomCase` function for `n`:

[image][image][image][image]

4 - First character capitalised

17 - Word capitalised

20 - Word left as lower case

24 - word left as lower case

However all four words have had the first letter capitalised:

[image]:

I've generated many passwords and they always seem to come out in the same way - first letter capitalised only. Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: Create array of valid password chars, i.e. `char[] passwordChars = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', etc. }`, then create string builder. Then append random index from `passwordChars` passwordLen times.

Comment: that's what `TextInfo.ToTitleCase` do ... and you have use it in 2 cases ... but obviously only first is used ... the problem is differenece between `and` and `or` ... **numbers between 1 and 29 are always biger(or eq) than 1 or smaller(or eq) than 9**

Comment: Why it has +1? this looks like a typo and not deserve +1

Comment: Your cases overlap because you're using or logic instead of and. For example,. instead of `(n >= 1 || n <= 9)` it should be `(n >= 1 && n <= 9)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either create an instance of Random inside of the class or you need to seed it every time you create it. You also should use && because you want both tests in the if to hold true.

If I use the following code:

```
    private static string randomCase(string word)
    {
        string changed;
        Random r = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
        int n = r.Next(1, 29);

        // Output number to check it's not the same each time
        //MessageBox.Show(n.ToString());
        //Console.WriteLine(n.ToString());
        if (n >= 1 && n <= 9)
        {
            // First letter capatalised
            changed = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(word.ToLower());
            return changed;
        }
        else if (n >= 10 && n <= 19)
        {
            // Word capitalised 
            changed = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(word.ToUpper());
            return changed;
        }
        else if (n >= 20 && n <= 29)
        {
            // Word left as lower case
            return word;
        }

        return null;
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Your code goes here
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(randomCase("heLLo"));
    }
```

I will get the following output:

```
HELLO
HELLO
Hello
heLLo
HELLO
Hello
Hello
HELLO
HELLO
HELLO
```